# jQuery $(this) selector is not working within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, this

[image: Sub Menu]

I'm trying to make a function that will be fired with the 'onclick' event of a procedurally added div.hb-menu-subMenuToggle element. The function works when using the initial selector as anything but '$(this)'

```
// FUNCTION: hbMenuSubToggle()
// Toggles CSS classes for animation of .hb-menu-sub-open. Fires when clicking the div element with .hb-menu-subMenuToggle class 
function hbMenuSubToggle(){

    // TESTING: This works as far as opening the submenus; however, it does not open only the submenu that is a direct sibling of the hb-menu-subMenuToggle element.
    $('a.withSubmenu').siblings('ul').toggleClass('hb-menu-sub-open');

    // DESIRED EFFECT: Does not work
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggleClass('hb-menu-sub-open');
};
```

Here's a link to the 
[Codepen Project](http://codepen.io/jbscott/pen/ojqaom)

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: change `$(this)` with a variable and use that variable as function's parameter instead.

Comment: get rid of `onclick` and use a jQuery event handler. There is no point using obtrusive script and unobtrusive combined. `onclick` only provides element access if you pass in `this` as argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be to use jQuery event handlers rather than using `onClick` and a function inline in your HTML.

For example if you place this within your `$(document).ready()` it will attach a click event handler to all `A` elements in your top menu. When it is clicked you will be able to get `$(this)` (which is the `A` element) and then traverse to its parent (the `UL` element) and then find the child `UL` elements (the sub menu) to toggle the class.

```
$('#main-nav>ul>li').on('click', '>a', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggleClass('hb-menu-sub-open');
});
```

Similarly your function to show the main menu could also be written as follows

```
$(document).on('click', '.hb-menu-btn', function(){
    $('.hb-menu-btn, .hb-menu, .hb-menu-page').toggleClass('hb-menu-open');
});
```

See it working on CodePen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOKQOJ

Answer (score 0):

```
function hbMenuSubToggle(divyouneed){

// TESTING: This works as far as opening the submenus; however, it does not open only the submenu that is a direct sibling of the hb-menu-subMenuToggle element.
$('a.withSubmenu').siblings('ul').toggleClass('hb-menu-sub-open');

// DESIRED EFFECT: Does not work
divyouneed.siblings('ul').toggleClass('hb-menu-sub-open');
};
```

and use it

```
hbMenuSubToggle($(this))
```

Answer (score -2):

for $(this) you have to had selected one element before. In a function you dont have it like that.. So it will only work if you select it directly and not with $(this)

```
function hbMenuSubToggle() {
  $('.blablabla').blablabla();
}
```

And read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) to find out more about jQuerys basics

Comment: Answer doesn't really make any sense

Comment: My english is just bad ^^ If you would understand what I mean it would make sense...

Comment: Try using a translation service.